# How can I turn this boolean method into a recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, boolean, palindrome

So for my CS homework assignment I have to, "Write a Boolean method that uses recursion to determine whether a String argument is a palindrome. The method should return true if the argument reads the same forward and backward" Now, my code works as intended, but its not a recursive method, and i'm not quite sure how I can make it a recursive method. Please let me know! Thanks!

```
public class CS142hw3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        palindrome();
    }

    static boolean palindrome() {
        String word = "kayak";
        String reverse = "";
        int len = word.length();

        for (int r = len - 1; r >= 0; r--)
            reverse = reverse + word.charAt(r);

        if (word.equals(reverse)) {
            System.out.println("True");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("False");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take the first and last character, compare the two - if they match, call the recursive method with both of them removed, continue until the length of the string is less than or equal to 1.

Comment: huh, good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When implementing a recursive function, the edge/exit conditions should be defined.

For example, if an input string is `null`, it is not a palindrome.

If the length of the input string is less than 2 - that is a string is empty or contains only one character, it is a palindrome.

Otherwise, check the first and the last characters *or codepoints* of the input string are equal (using `String::charAt` or `String::codePointAt` respectively) AND if the remaining string is a palindrome (the remaining string can be obtained using `String::substring`).

An example code:

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
    if (null == input) return false;

    int len = input.length();
    if (len < 2) return true;

    return input.codePointAt(0) == input.codePointAt(len - 1) 
        && isPalindrome(input.substring(1, len - 1));
}
```

Disclaimer: This method does not preprocess the input string to convert all characters to the same case, then remove whitespaces and/or punctuation marks to check such palindrome phrases as `Top spots`, `Was it a cat I saw?` etc..

Comment: thank you! This was very helpful!